# Custom Field: how to save array of multiple key-values in WordPress

Tags: custom-field, array

I have this kind of data on my database:

```
<wp:postmeta>

    <wp:meta_key>
        <![CDATA[property_icalendar_import_multi]]>
    </wp:meta_key>
    
    <wp:meta_value> <![CDATA[a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"feed";s:86:"https://www.example.com/ics-files/property.ics";s:4:"name";s:20:"IMPORT_1";}i:1;a:2:{s:4:"feed";s:56:"https://www.example.com/ical/property.ics";s:4:"name";s:16:"IMPORT_2";}}]]>
    </wp:meta_value>
    
</wp:postmeta>
```

As you can see, on meta_value I have two pairs of serialized data "name1/feed1" and "name2/feed2".

I wish to add, via custom fields, more instances to that array "name3/feed3)".
But I don't know how to do it.

I was able to retrive the data so far:

```
    <?php
    $property_icalendar_import_multi = get_post_meta($edit_id, 'property_icalendar_import_multi', true);

    if(is_array($property_icalendar_import_multi)){
            foreach($property_icalendar_import_multi as $key=>$feed_data){
                print $feed_data['name'];
                print $feed_data['feed'];
            }

        }else{
            esc_html_e('nothing');
        }

    ?>
```

My question is now, how can I update (edit or add) this data with a metabox?

I know I have to use `update_post_meta` but I'm not sure how.

Can someone point me on the right direction?

Comment: How this data being saved? Do you already have a metabox for that?

Comment: I need to create the metabox but I don't know how to adapt it to my needs

Comment: [This](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/) will help you to get started.

Comment: Ok thanks, my problem is I can create an "average" metabox to updat a "classic" plain custom field, but I don't know how to create a metabox that can update KEY/VALUE and append new information to the table...